# Show that a function is constant

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity

Let $S$ be a non-empty set of real numbers such that if $a,b$ are distinct elements in $S$, then $|a-b|\geq 1/2014$. Let $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be such that the range of $f$ is a subset of $S$. If $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb R$, show that $f$ is a constant function.

I know that if $f'(x)=0$ for all $x \in S$ then $f$ is a constant function on $S$. But how can I use this to solve the question here? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Hint (essential the intermediate value theorem in disguise):

Since $f$ is continuous, it maps connected sets into connected sets. The connected sets in $\mathbb{R}$ are the intervals (treat points as degenerate
intervals).

Hover over for details:

> So, suppose $a,b \in f(\mathbb{R})$ with $a<b$. Then we must have $[a,b] \subset f(\mathbb{R})$ which contradicts the assumption that two distinct points in the the range are at least ${ 1\over 2014}$ apart. Hence the range consists of just one point.

Comment: How exactly did you reach the contradiction?

Comment: If $a<b$ then since $f(\mathbb{R}) \subset S$ is a connected set, and $a,b \in f(\mathbb{R})$, we must have $[a,b] \subset f(\mathbb{R})$ (otherwise it is easy to show that $f(\mathbb{R})$ is not connected). Then you can find a point arbitrarily close to $a$ (or $b$) in $f(\mathbb{R})$. This contradicts the statement that any two distinct points in $S$ are separated by at least ${ 1\over 1024}$.

Comment: So, first we assumed that $f$ is not constant right? Then we reached this contradiction which means that $f$ has to be constant?

Comment: Well, yes, if I assume that $a<b$ and $a,b \in f(\mathbb{R})$ then it is not constant. Correct, it means that one of the assumptions is incorrect. In this case that means the assumption that there exists at least two distinct points in the range is incorrect.

Comment: How would you defined a connected set?

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_space.

Answer (score 0):

Note that we can't necessarily talk about $f'$, since $f$ might not be differentiable.

**Hint:** use the intermediate value theorem.

Comment: So the Intermediate Value Theorem says: Suppose $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and $k$ is between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$, then, there exists $c \in (a,b)$ such that $f(c)=k$.. That's what I should use right? But I am confused with the $|a-b|\geq 1/2014$ part.

Comment: Suppose f(a) does not equal f(b). choose a number n between f(a) and f(b) that is within 1/2014 of f(b). IVT guarantees there is an x such that f(x)= n. However, this is a contradiction